# Classic ASP Executing a Stored Procedure from an href

Tags: asp-classic

I have a an index.asp page that displays data from a SQL 2005 DB. On that index page I have the courses that a user which has already been selected in a drop down menu has taken. I want to open a new page test-results.asp which display the actual test they took by clicking the course Title. My stored procedure spGetCourseResultsByID retrieves the data using the following parameters @MedLicID, @TestID. I have no idea how to go about doing this. I never had to support classic asp before.

Answer (score 0):

That's a little broad as we don't know anything about the link, or the stored procedure.

1. retrieve the values of the link parameters, if any, using request.querystring.

2.
pass the parameters to the stored procedure using ADO command object
Here's an example but it will need to be modified for the actual stored procedure

```
 Function GetTest()
    Dim cmd, cn
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn
    With cmd
        .CommandText = "spGetCourseResultsByID"
        .Parameters.Append  .CreateParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
        .Parameters.Append  .CreateParameter("@MedLicID", adVarChar, adParamInput,50,MedLic_ID)
        .Parameters.Append  .CreateParameter("@TestID", adVarChar, adParamInput,50,Test_ID)
        .execute
        strResponse = Cint(.Parameters(0).value )
    End With
    With Response
        if strResponse > 0 then
            .Write strSuccess
        else
            .Write strFailure
        end if
    End With
End Function
```